# W3 Total Cache gives out Server 500 error

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, caching

I have a website which runs on wordpress, Every other plugin on the website works fine except W3 Total cache, Every time i enable any of its feature, the site goes down giving me a server 500 error.

I tried every method available online about the issue like removing lines of browser caching code on .htaccess , checking permissions on wp-content folder and plugins folder & uploads folder, removing the installation completely and installing it back again, using a dev build of W3 total cache.

Basically it doesnt occur with only W3 total cache, No caching plugins works and gives out the same error. I tried deleting the advanced-cache.php file that gets created in wp-content once i save the settings on the cache plugin and the site gets back up again, but once i save the options on the cache plugin again, the issue keeps occuring again.

Im running on LAMP stack on Ubuntu 14.04, Php5 , I checked the error log and this is all its gives out :

```
[:error] [pid 15548] [client 128.199.153.33:47477] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function get() on a non-object in /home/admin/web/avaskart.mv/public_html/wp-shop/wp-includes/cache.php on line 123
```

I tried replacing the cache.php with a new cache.php from a new wordpress download. It didn't help either.

Comment: This W3 Total Cache destroyed my site as well, and I am still trying to find the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing ZendOpcache resolved this problem for me

```
yum install php-pecl-zendopcache
```

[How to install zend opcache on CentOS 6](https://gistpages.com/posts/install_zend_opcache_on_centos_6)

To check if opcache is already installed you can use "php -v"